# Why PostgreSQL execution time is fast but respond is slow?

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

Using `Google Cloud PostgreSQL` the execution time of a simple query is **3ms** on the Google Console, but when I send the request from my Python on my Mac, it takes 4 seconds to get the respond and print it.

I do create a connection every time I run the script :

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + database)
```

and then I send query with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(e, engine)
```

Is this something that slow down the round trip? Should I not create a connection every time? How can I get a much faster respond ?

3ms for the query grows to 4 seconds getting the final respond - is this going to improve if I run it as a web client **sending a normal REST API request** ?

Comment: How much data are you retrieving? Number of rows? Approximate size of the data?

Comment: printing things is pretty expensive as well. In order to get a significant measure, just discard the rows you've retrieved. This way you know better where the time is going. And if possible, also record the time of the first row (that time isn't exact as Postgres might retrieve a bunch of rows to send first, but at least it marks the point in time where your program can start doing something with the result set)..

Comment: The network bandwidth can be also an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I am printing 4-10 rows of data with 6 columns, this can't turn 4ms to 4 seconds, maybe the python build operation ? bandwidth is not the issue for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to test the performance inside the code. This way you could measure the time it takes it line of your code and decide if this is because your environment ( for example the building time of your script) or it is taking more time due to the response from the server side.

To to that you can use the [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) Python library. An example on how to do this could be:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

#
# Your code stuff
#

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print('It took {} seconds to run your code'.format(elapsed_time))
```